# Combining a MP2307 (12 V to 5 V) & AMS1117-3.3 (5 V to 3.3 V)

Tags: power-supply, esp32, step-down

Powersource is from a motorcycle battery (12 V) for powering my device (a ESP32 MCU) and I thought combining a MP2307 (12 V to 5 V) & AMS1117-3.3 (5 V to 3.3 V) would make my device last longer. Is that okey? Did anyone have a similar experience?